# unable to install RMySQL package, error c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: not found

Tags: r, rmysql

I use windows 10, installed MySQL under "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7", installed R under "D:\R\R-3.3.2", installed Rtools under "D:\Rtools", installed RStudio under "D:\RStudio". then i followed below steps to install RMySQL package:

1: added MYSQL_HOME = C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\ in my environment variables.

2: created Renviron.site file under "D:\R\R-3.3.2\etc" with content: MYSQL_HOME=C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/

3: verified that Path value under my environment variables -> system variables does contain:D:\Rtools\bin;D:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin;...

4: run install.packages("RMySQL", type = "source") on RStudio.

But i get error message below:

```
> install.packages("RMySQL", type = "source")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RMySQL_0.10.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 54012 bytes (52 KB)
downloaded 52 KB

* installing *source* package 'RMySQL' ...
** 成功将'RMySQL'程序包解包并MD5和检查
** libs

*** arch - i386
rm -f RMySQL-init.o connection.o db-apply.o driver.o exception.o fields.o result.o utils.o RMySQL.dll
"D:/R/R-3.3.2/bin/i386/Rscript.exe" "../tools/winlibs.R"
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"D:/R/R-3.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I../windows/libmariadbclient-2.1.0/include    -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c RMySQL-init.c -o RMySQL-init.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: not found
make: *** [RMySQL-init.o] Error 127
Warning: 运行命令'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "D:/R/R-3.3.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "D:/R/R-3.3.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="RMySQL.dll" OBJECTS="RMySQL-init.o connection.o db-apply.o driver.o exception.o fields.o result.o utils.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RMySQL'
* removing 'D:/R/R-3.3.2/library/RMySQL'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"D:/R/R-3.3.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "D:\R\R-3.3.2\library" C:\Users\Xuan\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkjaBSm/downloaded_packages/RMySQL_0.10.9.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Xuan\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkjaBSm\downloaded_packages’
```

I see the error message says "c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: not found", this may be because i have RTools installed under D drive. I can install other R package successfully(which means Rtools can be used in R), but i don't know why this installation get the wrong path. Can anyone help to solve this? thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have the [Gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/) program installed?

Comment: @Llopis i used "system('g++ -v')" command in R, and get result as: 'Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=D:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=D:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (i686-posix-dwarf, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 
' , and i do find both gcc.exe and g++.exe under D:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin, so i think i do have gcc installed.

Comment: Strange, the error of "c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: not found" looks for gcc in another folder not in libexec, maybe you could move everything to a gcc folder. But I don't know enough R to know why it expects gcc to be there or how to tell R gcc is somewhere else

Comment: @Llopis i copied the whole Rtools folder to C drive, this time it worked. so strange!

Comment: Nice to hear! Post what worked to you as an answer, in order to help other people! (Also consider informing to the R community or to the GCC community)

Answer (score 0):

this issue was fixed by copying the whole Rtools folder to C drive. R can load RMySQL package correctly although this consumed quite a lot of space of my system drive.